# Flutter TextFormField: Align text description on left of entry field

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Good day, I am creating TextFormFields in Flutter and I am getting a bit frustrated that I can't have Text on the left of the entry input that STAYS there.

hintText disappears when you enter the field.

prefixText only appears after you enter the field.

prefixIcon does exactly what I want, but I want Text instead of an icon.

[image]

The above image uses prefixIcon and hintText.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to replace the icon I currently have with permanent Text instead, please? Thank you for any and all assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `prefixText` property in decoration.

```
TextField(
   controller: _textController,
   keyboardType: TextInputType.number,

   decoration: InputDecoration(            
     hintText: 'Enter a valid ZIP-Code',
     errorText: _hasInputError ? "ZIP-Code is too short" : null,
     counterText: _textController.text.length.toString(),
     helperText: "ZIP-Code of shipping destination",
     labelText: "ZIP-Code",
     prefixText: "DE - ",
     suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.airport_shuttle), 
   ),
),
```

Refer this [link](http://www.bytebau.com/flutter-textfield-how-to/)

I think you cannot use `prefixIcon` when using `decoration`.

Comment: As mentioned in my question, prefixText only appears once you click on the entry form. Which doesn't help user's see what they're supposed to enter beforehand. But thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

prefixIcon takes in a Widget type so you can pass a Widget into it if you want

```
TextFormField(        
  controller: _passwordController,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Password",
    prefixIcon: CircleAvatar(
      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(kDefaultProfilePicture),
    ) // You can replace this with a Text("") widget,
    suffixIcon: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.visibility),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `prefixIcon` with an `UnconstrainedBox`:

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: UnconstrainedBox(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        child: Text("Date:")
      )
    )
  )
)
```